# package does not exist when running the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have this error when tryin to run the application spring boot

java: package com.example.openapi.api does not exist

but the build (mvn clean install) is successful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Xiz.png)

I don't understand what is the problem !

Comment: It's difficult to understand the issue without any context of the project. Could you add screenshots of your project structure to the question?

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to do `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart`. If it doesn't help close the project `File | Close Project` and the IDE, open the project in OS file explorer and delete all .iml files and the .idea directory. After that, re-import the project in the IDE as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm afraid it may be a problem with your IDE.
Check if you have the last version and try to run also with other (Eclipse,STS,...).
I hope this help you.